# Can we run a pivot to make 1 record to multiple records in linux

Tags: text-processing

We have data as below

```
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100,200,300
```

Can we run any pivot/loop to dive above data into multiple records

```
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|200
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|300
```

As per the last column multiple values with comma delimeter , number of records should be created

Is there any way we can do in linux shell ?

Comment: Does it need to be with the shell? Awk is better suited to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use the shell itself for this.

Another awk implementation

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} {split($NF,a,","); for(i in a) {$NF = a[i]; print}}' data
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|200
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|300
```

or with [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --nidx --fs '|' nest --explode --values --across-records --nested-fs ',' -f 4 data
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|200
 ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|300
```

or more compactly

```
mlr --nidx --fs '|' nest --evar ',' -f 4 data
```

If you *really* need to use a shell, then with a suitably recent bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='|' read -a fields; do 
  IFS=',' read -a vals <<<"${fields[ -1]}"
  unset 'fields[ -1]'
  for v in "${vals[@]}"; do
    printf '%s|' "${fields[@]}" 
    printf '%s\n' "$v"
  done 
done < data
```

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
awk -F "," '                      #Sets field separator to ,
    NF<2{print;next}
    {
        print $1                  #Print first line up to ,
        sub(/[^|]*$/,"",$1)       #Remove all that is after | in $1
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){       #Print each remaining field after the first field
            printf "%s%s\n",$1,$i
        }
    }
' file
```

Sample file:

```
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100,200,300
ABC|BA00|
ABC|RAM|BANGALO00|200,300
```

Output:

```
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|200
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|300
ABC|BA00|
ABC|RAM|BANGALO00|200
ABC|RAM|BANGALO00|300
```

Comment: This answer also works perfect

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

s="ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100,200,300"

header="$(echo "$s" | rev | cut -d'|' -f2- | rev)"

list="$(echo "$s" | rev | cut -d'|' -f1 | rev)"

IFS=','
for i in $list
do
    printf "%s|" "$header"
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

Output:

```
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|100
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|200
ABC|RAM|BANGALORE|300
```

Comment: This answer as well works perfect